# S and T are both subspaces of P

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't know if this question is true or false:

"Let P be the space of all polynomials (of any degree) and let S be the set of all polynomials whose greatest power is even and T, the set of all polynomials with all their powers are even. Then S and T are both subspaces of P."

I am studying linear algebra and I have this question. I know that a vector subspace is the subset of a vector space, which satisfies by itself the definition of vector space with the same operations as V the original vector space.

Comment: If you add two polynomials in $S$, is the result always a polynomial in $S$?

Comment: To be a subspace, you have to check to see if it is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication (and is nonempty/aka contains 0)